# Check Camel body size programatically, Java and Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am using Camel 2.18 and Java 8. Is there any way to check size of the message in Camel so that I could validate it ?

So for example I have a processor that has access to the body:

```
Message msgIn = exchange.getIn();

msgIn.getBody()
```

Now I would like to check size that body takes in memory.

Reason for that is that I must raise an exception if a body is larger than 1MB.

The message that is POSTed to my Camel Endpoint is just simple json:

```
{
    "field1": "b14",
    "fieldWithContent": "there may be something big",
    "field3": 0
}
```

Comment: When you say "check size of the message in Camel" - do you mean within Camel route? If yes, please specify which DSL are you using XML or Java?

Comment: Convert body to string and do a length. You can easily then calculate the size of the string.

Comment: If the HTTP POST is not chunked then you can find the size of the body from the Content-Length HTTP header in the Camel message. However for a more general solution you would need to check this such as converting the body to string/byte[] and then check its size.

Comment: Thank you I will use Content-Length header.